# Big O for Item Response Theory Function

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I'm trying to determine Big O for two competing functions. In item response theory (IRT) these are referred to as information functions. Below are two functions (expressed in R code).

```
itemInfo1 <- function(theta, b){
        p <- 1 / (1 + exp((theta - b)))
        q <- 1 - p
        result <- p * q
        result
}

itemInfo2 <- function(theta, a, b, c, D = 1.7){
    p <- c + (1 - c) / (1 + exp(-D * a * (theta - b)))
    q <- 1 - p
    result <- (D^2*a^2*(q/p * ((p - c)/(1-c))^2))  
    result
}
```

I believe the first function runs in linear time and is O(n). The second function has the squared term and I believe, after removing the lower level terms, would run in quadratic time, O(n^2).
In my simulations, both functions appear to run in linear time.

```
library(microbenchmark)
K <- 10000
a <- runif(K, 0,1.5)
b <- runif(K, -4,4)
c <- runif(K, 0, .5)
L <- seq(from = 10, to = K, by = 10)
mat <- matrix(0, length(L),  2)
for(i in 1:length(L)){
    mat[i,] <- summary(microbenchmark(itemInfo1(0, b[1:(L[i])]), itemInfo2(0, a[1:(L[i])], b[1:(L[i])], c[1:(L[i])]), times=1000L))$mean
}
```

The second function is seemingly more expensive than the first, but plots don't suggest it runs quadratically.

My understanding of how to derive Big O asymptotics for functions is preliminary and appreciate reactions to how I might better understand the run time between these functions.

Answer (score 0):

Big-O notation w.r.t. runtime is used to indicate how the time to execute the function scales with the size of the input. In your case, the size of your inputs will hardly matter at all. Regardless of the values of `theta`, `a`, `b`, `c` and `D`, each function simply performs a constant number of operations and returns the result. This would make both functions `O(1)`. The fact that one of the functions uses a squared term has no bearing on this, and in fact I think the `exp()` will be the most expensive part of the function.

Technically, the operations will take slightly longer on larger numbers, but unless you're using *very* large numbers this difference will be negligible.